# Basis of subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Vectors (1, 2, 3, 4) and (1, 1, 1, 1) are space $\mathbb{R}^4$ for basis of subspace U.

Are the vectors (2, 3, 4, 5) and (0, 1, 2, 3) also basis for U?

What should I do first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the three things you need to check. There is theory you can lean on so that you don't have to check all of it directly, but ultimately, these are what you are asked for:

1. Does $U$ contain $(2, 3, 4, 5)$ and $(0, 1, 2, 3)$?
2. Does the space spanned by $(2, 3, 4, 5)$ and $(0, 1, 2, 3)$ contain $(1, 2, 3, 4)$ and $(1,1,1,1)$ and by extension all of $U$?
3. Are $(2, 3, 4, 5)$ and $(0, 1, 2, 3)$ linearly independent?

Point 1. in detail: We have
$$
(2, 3, 4, 5) = (1, 2, 3, 4) + (1, 1, 1, 1)
$$
and thus $(2, 3, 4, 5)$ is contained in $U$. Similarily, we have
$$
(0,1,2,3) = (1, 2, 3, 4) - (1, 1, 1, 1)
$$
which means that $(0, 1, 2, 3)$ is also contained in $U$.

Comment: How to do the 1st one? How to check whether the U contain those vectors or not? Also I am not sure how to do this spanning thing (number two)? The third point I can make myself.

Comment: 1) You see whether you can combine the two vectors $(1, 2, 3, 4)$ and $(1,1,1,1)$ (by multiplication with real numbers and vector addition) to make each of the two other vectors. 2) The same thing, just the other way (i.e. swap the two pairs of vectors around).

Comment: Okay? Uhmm, Could you possibly show me how to do it in practice? (I missed the lecture and therefore I don't have the lecture notes with me)

Comment: @MariaMagdalena Something like that will probably do.

Answer (score 0):

$(1, 2, 3, 4)$ and $(1, 1, 1, 1)$ are basis of subspace $U$.

Are the vectors $(2, 3, 4, 5)$ and $(0, 1, 2, 3)$ also basis for $U$?

First of all are this last two vectors in $U$?

$(2, 3, 4, 5)=\lambda(1, 2, 3, 4)+\mu(1, 1, 1, 1)$

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 \lambda +\mu =2 \\
 2 \lambda +\mu =3 \\
 3 \lambda +\mu =4 \\
 4 \lambda +\mu =5 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

for $\lambda = 1,\mu = 1$

In a similar way for $\lambda = 1,\mu = -1$ the other vector is in $U$

Are they linearly independent?

Yes because $h(2, 3, 4, 5)+k(0, 1, 2, 3)=(0,0,0,0)\Rightarrow h=0,k=0$

Finally consider any vector $v\in U$

Then $v=a(1, 2, 3, 4)+b(1, 1, 1, 1)=(a + b, 2 a + b, 3 a + b, 4 a + b)$ for some real pair $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$

Are there reals $h,k$ such that $v=h(2, 3, 4, 5)+k(0, 1, 2, 3)=2 h, 3 h + k, 4 h + 2 k, 5 h + 3 k)$

we should solve the system

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 2 h=a+b \\
 3 h+k=2 a+b \\
 4 h+2 k=3 a+b \\
 5 h+3 k=4 a+b \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

which gives one and only one solution $h=\dfrac{a+b}{2},\;k= \dfrac{a-b}{2}$

therefore $(2, 3, 4, 5)$ and $(0, 1, 2, 3)$ is a basis for $U$

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped me! In addition, I should also complete {(1,6,11,16)} basis for subspace U. How to do that?

Comment: @MariaMagdalena I don't understand. What do you mean with "complete"? To write another vector which makes a basis together with $\{(1,6,11,16)\}$?

Comment: Indeed! That's what I mean! (Sorry, english is not my native so translating mathematical words can be difficult at times).

Comment: First $(1,6,11,16)\in  U$ because $(1,6,11,16)=5 (1,2,3,4)-4 (1,1,1,1).\quad$  then we build another vector in $U$ which is linearly independent with the first. $$(2, 7, 12, 17)$$ is good because $$a(1,6,11,16)+b(2, 7, 12, 17)=(0,0,0,0)$$ only if $a=0;\;b=0$